# How can I fix Dalvik conversion errors during the build of an AndEngine game?

Tags: andengine

Recently I started learning [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) for Android. I began by implementing its examples, but I am getting problem with conversion of assets to the Dalvik format. I read elsewhere that if this problem comes up it could be settled by cleaning the project, but that did not help me.

```
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/adt/ISVGColorMapper.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/adt/SVG.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/adt/SVGAttributes.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/adt/SVGDirectColorMapper.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/adt/SVGGradient$SVGGradientStop.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/adt/SVGGradient.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/adt/SVGGroup.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/adt/SVGPaint.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/adt/SVGProperties.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/adt/SVGStyleSet.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/adt/filter/SVGFilter.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/adt/filter/element/ISVGFilterElement.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/adt/filter/element/SVGFilterElementGaussianBlur.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/exception/SVGParseException.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/opengl/texture/region/SVGTextureRegionFactory.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/opengl/texture/source/SVGAssetTextureSource.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/opengl/texture/source/SVGBaseTextureSource.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/opengl/texture/source/SVGResourceTextureSource.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/SAXHelper.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/SVGCircleParser.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/SVGEllipseParser.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/SVGLineParser.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/SVGNumberParser$SVGNumberParserFloatResult.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/SVGNumberParser$SVGNumberParserIntegerResult.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/SVGNumberParser.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/SVGParserUtils.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/SVGPathParser$PathParserHelper.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/SVGPathParser.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/SVGPolygonParser.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/SVGPolylineParser.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/SVGRectParser.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/SVGTransformParser.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/constants/ColorUtils.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/constants/ISVGConstants.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx processing org/anddev/andengine/extension/svg/util/constants/MathUtils.class...
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2011-09-30 14:55:33 - AndEngineRacer] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
[2011-09-30 14:57:32 - AndEngineRacer] Refreshing resource folders.
[2011-09-30 14:57:32 - AndEngineRacer] Starting incremental Pre Compiler: Checking resource changes.
[2011-09-30 14:57:32 - AndEngineRacer] Nothing to pre compile!
```

Comment: -1. This question is A) unreadable and B) too localized.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility for the source of the error (aside from bad intermediate files that could be resolved by cleaning the build) is a `.jar` file conflict, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar) on SO and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/22a92db16af2cb97?pli=1) in a Google Groups discussion forum.

In fact if you search Google for that error message (in quotes) and tack "AndEngine" on to the query, you find some even more specific occurrences: [here is a forum thread on the AndEngine site](http://www.andengine.org/forums/development/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-t2861.html) that explains some other `.jar` conflicts you may get with AndEngine.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you run multiple of these:

- Clean project
- Open/Close project
- (Eventually manually remove the contents of the bin folder.)
- Restart Eclipse